# If we use JavaScript MVC, then how can we still have animation for the view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc, canjs

If we use MVC for our webpages, especially, if we just modify the data (the model), and let the view just "observe" the model so that whatever changes are done to the model, the view will automatically be updated and reflects the model, how can we have animation still?

(**Update:** the view is just a template such as Mustache or Handlebars, for example, in can.js, so how can we animate?)

For example, say if we have two rows of cards.  The user can click on the first row to "move" a card into the second row.  So we can fade out the card in Row 1 and fade in the card to the end of Row 2 if we don't use MVC.  However, if we actually use 2 arrays and let 2 views observe these 2 arrays and no matter how the two array changes, the views reflect the model, then how can we actually have the fade out and fade in?  I can only think of if the view uses `opacity: 0` to not show the card, and use CSS transition so that we animate the disappearance and appearance of the cards, but then the cards will still show as empty space (still occupying screen space) after the opacity is 0.  The question is, how can we let view automatically show what the model is but still have animation?

Comment: The key point here is that data _change_ is observed. In other words, we start animation (view-related process) when card goes from one state to another. It's for view to decide when to begin this animation - and when to stop, too.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, I can't suggest a good solution. All the code I have seen suggested (for backbone for example) does this manually, meaning you move the elements yourselves using jquery. Angular seems the only framework that is tackling this issue http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

Comment: You might want to try this https://github.com/stevenvachon/can-transition

Answer (score 1):

Adding to a row and removing from a row are changes to a state. And animation is just a way to visualize the changes to state.

So, it is actually pretty straightforward: Decide an animation to be used for every state change (Add = Fade In, Remove = Fade Out...) and when that state change happens, perform the corresponding animation.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state clearly in the question, that the view is just a template... such as Mustache or Handlebars, so how can we animate?